# Remove ads-id, redirection info etc. from url

Tags: python, url

When I go to a webpage a lot of them tracks if I come from an ad, redirected from another webpage (e.g a priceagent page) etc.

I'm looking for a way to extract the "raw" url from a "noisy" url (in Python/Django)
e.g the url

`https://www.bilka.dk/produkter/ooni-koda-16-pizzaovn-med-cover-og-spade/200067354/?gclid=CjwKCAjwquWVBhBrEiwAt1KmwmgZ431kMKgDsw8CkpuXJsVJJhYAqFFl-ULlurmdeekkBIYhL5x-SRoC6cUQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds`

should end up being just

`https://www.bilka.dk/produkter/ooni-koda-16-pizzaovn-med-cover-og-spade/200067354/`.

I do not know that much of URL-creation but since the stuff after `?` is "parameters" (as far as I understand) I would assume, I could just remove everything to the right of the first encountered `?`.

Note, I want to clean it since I want to reduce the length of URLs, before storing it in a database (to avoid a lenght-issue since the database field is `VARCHAR(2048)`), such that a user can interact with it, i.e it is more important that link is still working than it is completely trimmed e.g if the results from the example-url above would end up being

`https://www.bilka.dk/produkter/ooni-koda-16-pizzaovn-med-cover-og-spade/200067354/?gclid=CjwKCAjwquWVBhBrEiwAt1KmwmgZ431kMKgD`

instead of

`https://www.bilka.dk/produkter/ooni-koda-16-pizzaovn-med-cover-og-spade/200067354/`

it is still a great reduction (and it still works).

Comment: Split the string on "?" and take 0 index for your use. This should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Code snippet for you, just make sure URL is not null before this operation:

```py
url = "https://www.bilka.dk/produkter/ooni-koda-16-pizzaovn-med-cover-og-spade/200067354/?gclid=CjwKCAjwquWVBhBrEiwAt1KmwmgZ431kMKgDsw8CkpuXJsVJJhYAqFFl-ULlurmdeekkBIYhL5x-SRoC6cUQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds"

url.split("?")[0]
```

Output:

```
'https://www.bilka.dk/produkter/ooni-koda-16-pizzaovn-med-cover-og-spade/200067354/'
```

Comment: As written that is what I thought off aswel. I just don't know if this always is the case i.e if there's cases where stuff after `?` is used for the URl and messes it up

Comment: It can because most GET request sends their query params after "?" only, so removing these can cause issues, but to be sure you will have to do some URL/data analysis at your end so that you can be sure for your use case.
In my experience, I have seen URLs where data after "?" is important to get the data from some websites.

Comment: I.e there isn't no universal way to detect a "raw" URL?

Comment: In my experience, not without opening it. (given format is correct)